# Reset all DB Connections for Select Dropdowns

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for a way to reset all Select dropdowns which pull info from a MySQL DB based on a filter, say 'Status=1'.

On one page, I have an option to change the status to something else which should negate this record from appearing in the other select boxes after it has been changed.

I am operating on a tabbed PHP page, so in theory, all Selects are on the same page, just in different Divs.

I don't think the '.selectedIndex = 0' option will work as I need to re-poll all the data.

I'd like something that utilizes jquery or PHP.

Hope someone can help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time looking around more and not receiving any solutions on this question, I decided to use the 'window.location.reload(true)' method.

...In case any one is wondering...